# Probability of an undetected error

Tags: probability, binomial-distribution

I have a problem and I'm wondering if my logic is correct:

Say I have a code word of six bits (e.g. $000000$ or $110110$. For this problem, there are a total of 8 code words that can be computed from a generator matrix, but I don't believe that's relevant here). These bits are transmitted in the form of a code word across a communications link with a bit error rate of $1E-6$. In the error-detecting code scheme used, only 1 error can be detected given any of the code words. The question asked is what is the probability of an error that is undetected in a code word?

My logic was to follow the flow of a binomial distribution. That if our random variable, X means to have an undetected error in the code word
$$P(X=1) = \binom61 (1\times10^{-6})^{1}(1-(1\times10^{-6}))^{6-1}$$

However, because the answer comes out to $5.99997E-6$ I'm not sure if this is correctly computed. Would someone verify this? Thanks so much for your help in advanced!

Comment: If I understood well, the probability that a digit is transmitted in a wrong way is $10^{-6}$, right? We need to find the probability that *exactly* one error is undetected or *at least* one error is undetected?

Comment: The question asks "Let's assume the BER on this communications link is 1E-6, what is the probability that an error is undetected in a code word?" - to me that says exactly one error being detected and 1E-6 for the error

Answer (score 2):

Single-error detection codes are parity-check codes. They check if the total number of bits is even or odd. By looking at your two given codewords, it is an even-parity-check code which means the number of $1$s is always even ($0$ is also even). Now when the number of errors is even, the code cannot detect it since the codeword in error can still be a valid codeword.

When the number of bit errors is even, a single-error detection code fails to detect it. The probability of undetected codeword-error is calculated by taking into account the number of combinations that $2$, $4$, and $6$ bits are in error:
 $$\Pr(\text{undetected})=\binom{6}{2}\varepsilon^2(1-\varepsilon)^{(6-2)}+\binom{6}{4}\varepsilon^4(1-\varepsilon)^{(6-4)}+\binom{6}{6}\varepsilon^6(1-\varepsilon)^{(6-6)}$$

where $\varepsilon=10^{-6}$ is the error probability of channel.

Comment: Would you mind explaining the why when you said "a single-error detection code fails to detect it"?

Comment: @Billy Thorton Single-error detection codes are parity-check codes. They check if the total number of bits is even or odd. By looking at your two given codewords, it is an even-parity-check code which means the number of $1$s is always even ($0$ is also even). Now when the number of errors is even, the code cannot detect it since the codeword in error can still be a valid codeword.

Comment: @Billy Thorton Example: when $110110$ is sent and there are 4 errors (bits 1,2,4,5) you get $000000$ which is also a codeword so it cannot detect that 4 errors exist.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. One last question: Why doesn't the 2 error bit case take care of the 4 and 6 error case? Don't they have at least 2 errors already?

Comment: 2-bit errrors (and 4 bits not in error): $110000$, $001100$, $10100$,... 4-bit errrors (and 2 bits not in error): $111100$, $111100$, $11110$,... , 6-bit errror (and 0 bits not in error): $111111$. You should count all of them.

Comment: Ah, so a sort of set behind each one. The one bit essentially can get detected thereby removing that set. Leaving us to count whats in the remaining, two error sets

Comment: Yes they are disjoint sets.