# single parity check performance close form

Tags: coding-theory

Does anyone know of a closed form solution for the bit and word probabilty of error for the single parity check codes (for AWGN channel)? These are $[n.n-1,2]_2$ codes that are the duals of the repetition codes $[n,1,n]_2$.

Comment: Maybe you find my answer to this question useful: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1891524/probability-of-an-undetected-error/1891553#1891553

Comment: thanks...that helps for hard decision decoding. I'm actually more interested in soft decision / optimal decoding performance; although for this code that may not be different.